# Psql COPY with constraint fails

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have a table like this in the server:

```
CREATE TABLE example_table (
id                          BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
name                        VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
status                      VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT status_enum CHECK (status IN ('old', 'new')),
UNIQUE (id, name)
);
```

And I have an SQL file, example.sql. The first line contain a header:

```
name_of_class,status
'CLASSNAME','old';
```

And I try to run a psql \copy to google server:

```
PGPASSWORD=password psql -d database --username username --port 5432 --host 11.111.111 << EOF
    BEGIN;
    \copy example_table(name,status) FROM example.sql DELIMITER ',' CSV Header
    COMMIT;
EOF
```

I then get this error:

```
ERROR:  new row for relation "example_table" violates check constraint "status_enum"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, 'CLASSNAME', 'old';).
CONTEXT:  COPY example_table, line 2: "'CLASSNAME','old';"
ROLLBACK
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Fix the input data so it doesn't violate the constraint anymore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that your source csv is using the `'` (single-quote) to quote all the columns. You could specify that as the quote character using the option [`QUOTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html)

The `\copy` command is trying to load `'old'` into the status column that checks that values are either `new` or `old`. The extra quotes violate the constraint.

```
\copy example_table(name,status) FROM example.sql DELIMITER ',' CSV Header QUOTE ''''
```

4 single quotes are required because 1 specifies the actual quote char, 1 to escapes the quote-character, and 2 encloses the escaped quote-character.

Comment: Cool, did not notice that. I did as you described, but I get this error now: ERROR:  missing data for column "status" \n
CONTEXT:  COPY example_table, line 3: "" \n
ROLLBACK

Comment: Nvm, it was me . Thank you very much for your effort, really appreciate it 