# Psql - COPY with query in csv file?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have an example.sql with csv format looking like this:

```
name,frame_identification
'Element', 1
```

I have been using COPY, which is working in this case

Question: Is it possible to have a query instead in frame_identification column? That is:

```
name,frame_identification
'Element', (select id FROM frame_identification WHERE frame='frame')
```

This is probability a follow up question from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46977345/psql-copy-with-constraint-fails)

Comment: No, it isn't possible.

Comment: , I see. Thanks for quick reply

Comment: Instead, `COPY` to an `unlogged` or `temporary` table then do an `insert into ... select ...` to do whatever data modification you need